# R Markdown: Change plot font size when knit to HTML?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using R Markdown to create an HTML document with various plots in ggplot2. However, the font size shrinks considerably whenever I knit to HTML compared to when I knit to a GitHub document.

I've tried `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev.args = list(pointsize = BIG_NUMBER)` but that didn't work. Any ideas? Looking for a solution that I can apply to all plots automatically, preferably with `knitr`. Please help!

Here's what it looks like when I knit to HTML:
[image]
Here when I copy from my R chunk output (what I want it to look like):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The font size is actually the same – the apparent change in font size results from different dimensions of the plot device used: the default device (where plots are displayed in RStudio when you run code in the console) is a different one than what is used by knitr. You may compensate for this by adjusting plot dimensions using chunk options.

- `out.width` and `out.height` set dimensions of the plot in the output.
- `fig.width` and `fig.height` set dimensions of the graphic device.

**Example:**

````r
```{r, out.height=400, out.width=800, fig.width=6, fig.height=3}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point()
```
````

[image]

````r
```{r, out.height=400, out.width=800, fig.width=4.5, fig.height=2.25}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point()
```
````

[image]

You may also apply options globally by including the below chunk.

````
```{r, include=F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.height=400, out.width=800, fig.width=6, fig.height=3)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for this reply! I just realized that text shrinks because I was using the `showtext` package. Perhaps then it's a problem with the package.